# 405 Error when I'm trying to search in twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I'm trying to do some searching in Twitter using jQuery. Unfortunately, It's returning only:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=django 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=django.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here's the code:

```
(function(){
    var Twitter = {
        init: function(){
            this.url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=django';
            this.fetch();
        },

        fetch: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: this.url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){ console.log(data); },
                error: function(data){ console.log(data); },
                beforeSend: this.setHeader
            })
        },

        setHeader: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HostCommonName', 'api.twitter.com');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth my_oauth_data');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Host', 'api.twitter.com');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Target-URI', 'https://api.twitter.com');
        }
    };

    Twitter.init();
})();
```

I've tested the same query with the same headers using REST Console extension for Google Chrome and It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It looks like (here's the [info](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10710)) you can't do OAuth authentication on client side.

So, the only solution here is to code this thing to be invoked on your server.